# Problem with 9 and 8 in a simple terminal to see which is the largest number

Tags: c#

my simple command to check wh is the biggest number, is not working with 9 and 8 in visual studio with C#

```
  using System.ComponentModel.Design;

  class Program
  {

    static void Main()
    {
        int n1;
        int n2;
        int n3;

        Console.WriteLine("Escreva o primeiro número: ");

        n1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Escreva o segundo número: ");

        n2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Escreva o terceiro número: ");

        n3 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


        if (n1 > n2 & n1 > n3)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("O maior número entre os 3 é o PRIMEIRO");
        }
        else if (n2 > n1 & n2 > n3)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("O maior número entre os 3 é o SEGUNDO");
        }
        else if (n3 > n1 & n3 > n2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("O maior número entre os 3 é o TERCEIRO");
        }
        else if (n1 == n2 & n2 == n3)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Todos os 3 números são IGUAIS!");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
        
    }
  }
```

Until then it worked perfectly, I just can't use these numbers repeatedly

CMD requests 3 numbers, if they are 9 or 8 the result simply does not appear

First number 99, second number 88 and third number 99:

[image]

But, does not return anything

Comment: I'm no C# expert but shouldn't those `&` operators be `&&`? I think `&` is a bitwise AND whereas `&&` is the (required) logical AND.

Comment: Consider [using debugger to step through your program](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25385174/7034621). Logically, there are 6 possible orders of 3 variables and your program covers only 4 of them.

Comment: @AdrianMole for booleans the result of `&&` and `&` will be the same, the difference being bitwise always evaluates left and right operand. I doubt this is the problem here, [`&` is still evaluated after comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/precedence-and-order-of-evaluation?view=msvc-170).

Comment: @AdrianMole: the difference between `&` and `&&` is irrelevant here. The problem is that none of the combined conditions allow for the combination where two of the values are the same and different from the third value.

Comment: Check your conditions for n1 = 99, n2 = 88 and n3 = 99 (and keep in mind the effect of the logic 'and'!).

Comment: @JohanDonne Actually a very good point. Maybe LarsTech can reopen this?

Comment: @LarsTech Care to reconsider the duplicate closure, in the light of the comments about the operators' equivalence in this case?

Comment: Also, I can't really use the fact that I'm really a C and C++ programmer as an excuse: The relative precedence of the `>`, `&` and `&&` operators are very similar in those languages to what they are in C#.

Comment: Why don't you put numbers into a collection (say, array). `Sort` then and then print?

Comment: Your conditions work if either all numbers are equal or the maximum is unique. They don't work if you enter the maximum twice, because none of them is greater then both others.

Comment: The simplest way to fix this in your existing code is probably to replace `>` with `>=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you probably should be using `&&` ([conditional logical `AND`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#conditional-logical-and-operator-)) instead of `&` ([logical operator `AND`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#logical-and-operator-)). It won't make any difference in your case, but can make in future ones.

Debugging would help you understand what's going on.

Check this out:

`if (n1 > n2 & n1 > n3)` -> `if (99 > 88 & 99 > 99)` -> `false`

`else if (n2 > n1 & n2 > n3)` -> `else if (88 > 99 & 88 > 99)` -> `false`

`else if (n3 > n1 & n3 > n2)` -> `else if (99 > 99 & 99 > 88)` -> `false`

`else if (n1 == n2 & n2 == n3)` -> `else if (99 == 88 & 99 == 88)` -> `false`

All of your conditions are evaluating to `false`, that's why it's not printing any messages.

Comment: Thanks i basically not made the if with two numbers equal.